# Symfony Annotation Inheritance

Tags: php, symfony, oop, inheritance, annotations

I've got a question about the inheritance of annotations in symfony.

Class A:

```
abstract class AController
{
  /**
   * Test action
   * @Route("/", name="test")
   * @Template("...")
   */
  public function testAction()
  {
      ...
  }
}
```

My question is if it is possible from Class B not only to inherit the function but also the route annotation. Or what a nice workaround would be. Something like:

```
class BController extend AbstractController
{
    public function testAction(){
        return parent::testAction();
    }
}
```

Comment: How would that work? If both the abstract class and several implemented classes share the same route definition, how should symfony know which action to call when that route is actually called?

Comment: but is there an annotation like @inheritParentAnnotation

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar solution for an admin subdomain on a project I'm working on. First, I tried to use your method and realized it isn't supported. So I set updated my configuration instead. The following configuration automatically restricts all routes in the /src/Controller/Admin directory to my admin subdomain and prefixes all the route names with "admin_".

```
# /config/routes/annotations.yaml
controllers:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/**/*
    type: annotation
    exclude: ../../src/Controller/Admin

admin:
    resource: ../../src/Controller/Admin/
    type: annotation
    host: admin.%site_name%
    name_prefix: admin_
....
```

There's a couple things to note here. First, "%site_name%" is a parameter defined in my project. Second, there seems to be a bug with the exclude option on route configurations where it only works if you use a glob pattern for resource option. Hence the "../../src/Controller/**/*".

This question is pretty old, but hopefully this helps someone.